# Java Mail Microsoft Exchange NTLM

Tags: java, spring, smtp, ntlm

I have searched online, but can't find a solution that works. I receive the following Exception:

```
Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
```

Below is my output:

```
JavaMail version 1.4.3
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc],  com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun  Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider [STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
 DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
 DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
 DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
 DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "NB-EX10-1.example.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 NB-EX10-1.example.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 1 May 2013 11:48:32 +0100
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "NB-EX10-1.example.com", port: 25

EHLO PC-9MF9LP1.example.com
250-NB-example.com Hello [192.168.22.123]
250-SIZE
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS
250-AUTH NTLM
250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-XEXCH50
250-XRDST
250 XSHADOW
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-ANONYMOUSTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-EXPS", arg "GSSAPI NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XEXCH50", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XRDST", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XSHADOW", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
DEBUG SMTP: mechanism PLAIN not supported by server
DEBUG SMTP: mechanism DIGEST-MD5 not supported by server
DEBUG NTLM: type 1 message: suppliedWorkstation: PC-9MF9LP1.example.com
DEBUG NTLM: type 1 message length: 61
AUTH NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAACAAAAAAAAA9AAAAHQAdACAAAABQQy05TUY5TFAxLk5FVEJVSUxERVIuUFJJVkFURQ==
535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
Exception : Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
```

I am using Spring 3.0 to use the JavaMail API as below:

```
<bean id="mailSenderBean" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="NB-EX10-1.example.com"></property> <!-- localhost-->
    <property name="username" value="myusername"></property>
    <property name="password" value="password"></property>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.port">25</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="mail.smtp.auth.ntlm.domain"></prop>-->
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

We are using Microsoft Exchange Server 2010. I need to connect using NTLM only.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I face to this problem and find out 'mail.smtp.port' should be 587 because When an email client or outgoing server is submitting an email to be routed by a proper mail server, it should always use SMTP port 587 as the default port.